# Unknown hot water line under sink

Tags: plumbing

I am wondering why I have an extra hot water supply line under the sink the disappears to the wall.  The thin copper has a needle valve attached to it.  There seems to be one in every room with a sink, i.e. the master bath room has this line in one of the two sinks.

Comment: Could be a hot water circulating system, with a pump on a timer somewhere so that it comes on in the morning, making the water hot without having to "run" the faucet.

Comment: We do have a hot water recirculating pump.  That’s what I thought initially.  Should’t there be just one return loop from the farthest end of the hot water line?  And why are there needle valves?  You may be correct.  But how do we test?